# getFilesDir() vs Environment.getDataDirectory()

Tags: android

I want to replace one context method with Environment variable.
But not sure if they mean the same.

What is the difference between

`getFilesDir()` and `Environment.getDataDirectory()` ?

How can I get `data\data` as a from of `data\data\com.Myapp` using `Environment Variable`?

Comment: What did you mean by ~"**one context method**"?

Comment: I recommend you read this excellently written article explaining the difference: https://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-to-correctly-store-app-specific-files-in-android/ It's actually much easier than these answers and the docs would have you believe.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29)  and [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29)

> **public File getFilesDir ()**
>
> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where
> files created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` are stored.
>
> **public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()**
>
> Return the primary external storage directory. This directory may not
> currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their
> computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has
> happened. You can determine its current state with
> `getExternalStorageState()`.
>
> > Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
> > can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
> > all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
> > an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
> > device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
> > mounted as a filesystem on a computer.
>
> On devices with multiple users (as described by UserManager), each
> user has their own isolated external storage. Applications only have
> access to the external storage for the user they're running as.

If you want to get your application path use `getFilesDir()` which will give you path   `/data/data/your package/files`

You can get the path using the `Environment` var of your `data/package` using the

`getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath();` which will return the path from the root directory of your external storage as
`/storage/sdcard/Android/data/your pacakge/files/data`

To access the external resources you have to provide the permission of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Check out the [Best Documentation to get the paths of direcorty](https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148)

Comment: how can i get `data\data` as from `data\data\com.Myapp` using EnvironmentVar?

Comment: You can get path using EnvironmentVar as `Environment.getDataDirectory()`. Check out my answer i have mentioned a link at the end which will guide you.

Comment: but it returns only `data` from `data\data\com.Myapp`

Comment: As i stated in answer `getFilesDir ()` returns the application's directory path whereas `getExternalStorage` which will used in context of `Environment` will only return the user's directory path. The thing which you want to achieve is not possible using `Enviroment.getFilesDir()` as the method `getFilesDir()` does not resides inside Enviroment namespace.

Comment: Try out this way `Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: @EladBenda2: Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

Answer (score 18):

[Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29) returns **user** data directory. And [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) returns **application** data directory.

Comment: how can i get `data\data` as from `data\data\com.Myapp` using EnvironmentVar?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You want to cut `data\data` part from `data\data\com.Myapp` path? Use `split("\")` method on this path(as String) and then join particular parts.

Comment: i want `{this path}` from EnvironmebtVars object to fill `{this path}\com.Myapp\`in my example `data\data`

Answer (score 2):

**[getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29)**

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

**[Environment.getDataDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29)**

Return the user data directory.

Comment: What may not be obvious is that the "user data directory" returned by getDataDirectory is the **system-wide** data directory (ie, typically so far /data) and *not* an application specific directory.  Applications of course are not allowed to write to the overall data directory, but only to their particular folder inside it or other select locations whose owner has granted access.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: No - this is meaningless.  Environment.getDataDirectory() is an **internal** system-wide folder, not something you should be using with **external** storage.  You are just abusing its name as a random custom directory type, but you should be using one of the type constants defined in Environment.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)