# Mkdirs does not create folder in internal storage (Android)

Tags: android, mkdir, internal-storage, mkdirs

I'm trying to create a folder in the internal storage of an app so I can download files to it. But it doesn't seem to work. I've been looking for a solution for hours and hours but I can't find one and it's starting to drive me crzay.

This the code to create the folder:

```
String intStorageDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString();
File folder = new File(intStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
folder.mkdirs();
```

This code always returns "DOES NOT EXIST":

```
File f = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/testthreepdf");
if(f.exists())
{
    Log.i("testApp", f.toString() + "EXISTS");
}
else        {
    Log.i("testApp", f.toString() + " DOES NOT EXIST");
}
```

These are the android permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Anybody know what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Environment.getDataDirectory() returns the top-level data folder shared by all apps. You can't create folders there. To create folders in your app's data folder, use getFilesDir() instead, like this:

```
String intStorageDirectory = getFilesDir().toString();
File folder = new File(intStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
folder.mkdirs();
```

You need a Context to call getFilesDir().

For more information about the difference between getDataDirectory() and getFilesDir(), see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230629/getfilesdir-vs-environment-getdatadirectory).

Answer (score 5):

Another problem (though not specifically causing any bug) is that READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE are non-existent in Android. They have no effect and should be removed from your manifest.