# Access Android Data Directory in Java

Tags: java, android

How can I access/read the Android data Directory?
I tried

```
File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().toString());
Log.w("File", "read? "+file.canRead());
Log.w("File", "write?"+file.canWrite());
```

but both return false. How can I fix this?
I already added the external permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: On which version of os are you testing?. You will need run time permissions on marshmallow

Comment: see this : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230946/2425682](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230946/2425682)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getFilesDir() vs Environment.getDataDirectory()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230629/getfilesdir-vs-environment-getdatadirectory)

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that `Environment.getDataDirectory()` returns the system data directory path, not the one for your app. That's why you don't have permission to read or write it.
There's essentially two ways to do it:

- Call `getFilesDir()` instead. Something like this: `File file = getFilesDir()` Note that this must be called from an Activity or Service Context.
- Append your package name to the path returned by `Environment.getDataDirectory()`, like this: `File file = new File( Environment.getDataDirectory() + "com.mycompany.myapp/")`